# jackson AfterburnerModule gives a warning in the log

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-modules

After enabling AfterburnerModule I am seeing the below warning message in the logs. Without AfterburnerModule everything works fine.

```
Sep 06, 2017 9:11:39 AM com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.BeanPropertyMutator _reportProblem
WARNING: Disabling Afterburner deserialization for class com.test.Child (field #0; mutator com.test.Child$Access4JacksonDeserializerdc6e0fab), due to access error (type java.lang.IllegalAccessError, message=tried to access method com.test.test2.Parent.setSurname(Ljava/lang/String;)V from class com.test.Child$Access4JacksonDeserializerdc6e0fab)

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.test.test2.Parent.setSurname(Ljava/lang/String;)V from class com.test.Child$Access4JacksonDeserializerdc6e0fab
    at com.test.Child$Access4JacksonDeserializerdc6e0fab.stringSetter(com/test/Child$Access4JacksonDeserializer.java)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.BeanPropertyMutator.stringSetter(BeanPropertyMutator.java:123)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SettableStringMethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableStringMethodProperty.java:60)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.deserialize(SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3807)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2797)
    at com.test.JacksonStuff.main(JacksonStuff.java:19)
```

My class are as follows:

```
package com.test.test2;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
public class Parent {
    @JsonProperty("surname")
    private String surname;    
    protected Parent() {
    }    
    public Parent(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }    
    protected void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }}
    package com.test;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import com.test.test2.Parent;

public class Child extends Parent {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String test;
    public Child() {
        super();
    }    
    public Child(String var1) {
        super(var1);
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }}

package com.test;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.AfterburnerModule;
import java.io.IOException;
public class JacksonStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        AfterburnerModule module = new AfterburnerModule();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        String json = "{\"surname\":\"abc\"}";
        Child value = mapper.readValue(json, Child.class);
    }}
```

How do I avoid getting this warning in the logs? I cannot modify parent.java as it is from a third party lib and not under my control.

Answer (score 1):

Because `void setSurname` is `protected`. Set it to `public`.

Comment: As I mentioned I cannot edit Parent.java. Some solutions that I have found so far: Child.java and Parent.java should be in same package. Change the visibility from protected to public for Parent#setSurname(). And Add @JsonIgnore annotation to Parent#setSurname().